# How to repair/setup Eclipse Java EE on OS X 10.7.3 and grant permissions for it?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, permissions, permission-denied

I can not update packages, can't clean project, can't build project.

**On building the project it writes me an error:**

The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/.../classes/com'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent
Unknown Java Problem

**When I'm trying to clean the project it reports:**

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project '...'.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Could not delete ....

**On update:**

android-sdk-macosx/temp/google_apis-15_r02.zip (Permission denied)

It looks like it do not gets permissions for system calls or something like that.
When I launch eclipse from terminal with: "./eclipse" after I had logged with "sudo -s" it gets all the permissions and cleans and builds projects but when I build the project in that way and launch it on either device or emulator, it crashes.

My question is - what do I need to do to grant all the permission to eclipse session? What I need to edit in .bash_profile? It also does not see working paths.

**In .bash_profile I have:**

export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-macosx/tools

and it does not help to see adb and etc, I must always provide full path's.

I have repaired the permissions in OS X, The eclipse ver.:

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

**P.S. My last interactions with eclipse were:**

Installed MAT, and updated 4.03 api's from 16 to 18, but I'm sure that the problem appeared before that, cause all these actions I couldn't do in simple session, but from sudo, and day before, it was fully working IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try - chown -R $me $folder - on the eclipse workspace or the project. Perhaps you started it with different users and got some inconsistent permissions that way.

Comment: Does not solve the problem, even with chown -R 777 android-sdk-macosx/

Comment: I have tried one more time with chmod, it solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Hope you get a stack trace which gives a reason. If not i would check for OS X java updates or maybe re create the project. I once had an issue with inconsistent project settings (eclipse crash related) - the only solution was to re-create the whole project.

Comment: thanks a lot, i ran `chown -R` for all workspace and after `clear` all works. My projects had root owner